# Как получить адрес ячейки, если известно значение этой ячейки в Excel, через Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, разработка-игр, openpyxl

Мне нужно узнать адрес ячейки, при условии, что я знаю его значение. Допустим, значение ячейки 123 и записано где-то в таблице. Мне нужно вытащить адрес ячейки, зная значение этой ячейки.

Если нужна дополнительная информация по вопросу, задавайте, я дам все что необходимо.

Comment: а к чему тут разработка игр?)

Comment: я тут почитал документацию к библиотеке и могу с точностью гарантировать, что там есть глава про парсинг, фильтры и подобноее. читайте))

Comment: @finally, Я делаю небольшую игру и для нее использую таблицу.

Comment: @finally, буду рад, если укажите раздел, потому что я никак найти не могу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашел как можно вывести координаты ячейки.

```
A1_column = sheet1['A1'].column
A1_row = sheet1['A1'].row
```

Comment: это хорошо, да вот только это не ответ.

Comment: можете расширить вопрос, либо прикрепить это как комментарий

Comment: либо же можете сами грамотно ответить на свой же вопрос, расписав все решение. в таком случае вы оставите подсказку будущим соискателям

Comment: @finally, Хорошо, я учту.